# Returning data where all categories exactly match

Tags: mysql

I have a documents table that I'm rendering out in a ui.

This ui has a set of select2 dropdowns for different category types and the dropdowns are populated data from a categories table.

Each of these dropdowns allows for multiple selections and will post a named array of values to the server.

What I'm hoping to achieve is to only display the relevant documents based on matching the posted `cat_id`'s within a `cat_type`

These are example tables

**Documents**

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | doc_title  | doc_version |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 | item 1     |           4 |
|  2 | document 2 |           3 |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

**Categories**

```
+----+--------+----------+
| id | cat_id | cat_type |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 |      1 |        3 |
|  1 |      7 |        2 |
|  1 |      4 |        2 |
|  2 |      7 |        2 |
+----+--------+----------+
```

An example might be querying `documents` where the `cat_id` = 7 and the `cat_type` = 2.
This should to return row 1 and 2 of the `documents` table.

What I'm having difficulty with is query `documents` for a match where multiple `cat_id`'s are declared for a `cat_type`.

An example might be querying `documents` where the `cat_id` = 7 and 4  and the `cat_type` = 2.
This should to return row 1 of the `documents` table.

I was thinking I could of used `WHERE cat_id IN (4,7) AND cat_type = 2`, however that returns results that match either `cat_id`.

How should I go about querying the data in order to return document entries that exactly match `cat_id`'s for a `cat_type`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cqan use the IN clause for that

```
SELECT 
`id`, `doc_title`, `doc_version` 
FROM Documents WHERE id in (SELECT `id` 
                            FROM Categories 
                            WHERE `cat_id` = 7  AND  `cat_type` = 2);
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Documents (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `doc_title` VARCHAR(10),
>   `doc_version` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Documents
>   (`id`, `doc_title`, `doc_version`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'item 1', '4'),
>   ('2', 'document 2', '3');
>
> CREATE TABLE Categories (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `cat_id` INTEGER,
>   `cat_type` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Categories
>   (`id`, `cat_id`, `cat_type`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', '3'),
>   ('1', '7', '2'),
>   ('1', '4', '2'),
>   ('2', '7', '2');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> `id`, `doc_title`, `doc_version` 
> FROM Documents WHERE id in (SELECT `id` 
>                             FROM Categories 
>                             WHERE `cat_id` = 7  AND  `cat_type` = 2);
> ```
>
> ```
> id | doc_title  | doc_version
> -: | :--------- | ----------:
>  1 | item 1     |           4
>  2 | document 2 |           3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dec33a8733adc9fc3fb9c5eb126aaa41)*

Comment: Thanks - I think that worked. I think I can extend this for multiple `cat_id`'s by adding additional `and` clauses - see here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e14eb803309e70fdb2ba979253c687dc

Comment: You can add more criteria to the where clause to get the right ids https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e613f1fa8513e78d7872e1a7b399340f  your query excludes id 2.